# How secure is Blackberry Persistence Store?

Tags: security, blackberry

with a 64 bit long as key and codesign, it's unbreakable, right?

Comment: is anything unbreakable?

Comment: If they ever figure out quantum computing...64 bits will seem like child's play.

Comment: It is unbreakable by a blackberry, if that is what you mean.  It probably takes a few minutes for a million node zombie cluster.

Answer (score 6):

It's unbreakable until someone convinces you they need your password to perform some routine maintenance.

[alt text http://www.brotherhoodmutual.com/theme/images/articles/phishing.jpg](http://www.brotherhoodmutual.com/theme/images/articles/phishing.jpg)

It's unbreakable until you need to write down your password somewhere because it's so long and complicated that you can't remember it.

[alt text http://www.hackingmovies.com/resources/wargames2.jpg](http://www.hackingmovies.com/resources/wargames2.jpg)

It's unbreakable unless you use your pet's name as a password.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](http://ihasahotdog.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/funny-dog-pictures-pets-name-password.jpg))</sub>